# Limit code duplication when decorating a function

Tags: c++, code-duplication

I’m fairly new to programming in c++ and would like to ask how to implement something in the most efficient way. Let’s say I got a class A with two functions foo and bar. Main will instantiate and object of A and will call foo. This class does something computationally expensive, where foo might call bar and vice versa, backtrack and so on until some result is computed. I now would like to implement something like a decorator for this class where the function bar now does the same as before but before returning e.g., prints some intermediate result, while keeping the original implementation available for cases in which these intermediate results are not wanted. Everything else stays the same.

I wonder I would implement something like this in the best way. I could of course add some if statement at the end of bar in class A and check some member variable which is set in main, but as these functions will be called a lot, this would add many additional checks which are not really needed, as one check in main would be sufficient. I could also create a copy of class A, let’s call it B, and modify bar there. But this would duplicate most of the code and would require subsequent changes to be made to both A and B. I could also make function bar in A virtual and have B derive from A and overwrite it, but then I would just simply have these checks in form of the dispatching decisions, wouldn’t I?

Comment: I'd use a logging library that can be configured on or off.

Comment: Checking a boolean is a lot cheaper than going through function call indirection (which is what your decoration would be). For the boolean check the implementation on the machine level would be a conditional jump on a specific memory location; modern CPUs' branch predictors eat this for breakfast. – For the decorator the decorator function location has to be loaded, then a jump or call to that location is made, which will load another location (your original function) and call that; since those function may be far apart, the branch detector has far less to work with.

Comment: @John Kugelman: how would this work if the decision if the intermediate results should be printed or not would still have to be made at runtime, but only once in main? Like, it still one binary and whether the prints should occur would be based on e.g., a flag in the parameters of the program

Comment: @datenwolf: I also thought so that jump prediction would probably take care of it anyway if the condition is basically fixed once the first foo is called for the rest of the lifetime of the object. I just wondered whether there is a idiomatic way of doing something like this

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency unless and until you have a noticeable efficiency problem. What you're trying to do, optionally print results to help you understand what's going on in your code -- that's precisely what loggers are for. Use a logger, then you can turn the logs on when you want to debug this code and turn them off when you don't. No need to reinvent the wheel, eh? :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman I know, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet, these prints are not a debugging feature. They can be useful for an actual user of the program, but if one does not need them, they just cause additional runtime without any use and runtime (aside of correctness) is the most important feature of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a bool parameter

```
class A{
    public:
    void foo(/*params*/,bool should_print=false){
        if (should_print){
            //print
        }
    }
    void bar(/*params*/,bool should_print=false){
        if (should_print){
            //print
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to print set the parameter should_print to true, otherwise don't pass it.

You can also use template for flag. so (INside class A)

```
template<bool should_print>
void bar(/*params*/){
    if constexpr (should_print){
        //print
    }
}
```

This will evaluate the if at compile-time so it will be even faster, but you will have to define template-funkctions in the heather for the class not in it's `.cpp`

Note `if constexpr` only works from `c++17` you can have a regular `if` if you use an older standard. any competent compiler will evauleate the if compile-time that way too

Comment: Default parameters don't result in multiple functions. They're just syntactic sugar that cause the default values to be passed at call sites if the arguments are omitted.

Comment: How does `should_print` get passed from `foo` to `bar` and vice versa? It needs to be added to all the calls of each. This goes for both versions. Can you update your answer to explain that?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I thought it was a member of the class because the OP suggested as much when he said he didn't want to do it that way because it resulted in lots of additional checks.

Comment: A class member would make sense. Your answer shows it as an argument, though, yeah?

Comment: @JohnKugelman with the default parameters you are right (I checked only templates generate more functions). In my 2nd example `bar()` is inside the class (foo too) but I didn't want to dupe the code I wrote.

Comment: @BotondHorváth yes, foo and bar are both members of class A. I just implemented it that way and the output is exactly what I was looking for. If this if statement is evaluated at compile time and would not be checked if the object of A is created with should_print being false, e.g. based on a switch in call parameters of the program, then this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @AILogic the template version (the 2nd) checks compile-time. by the way 1 if is fast, so I think you have to optimize the other part of your code for max speed.

Comment: @BotondHorváth Thanks! Out of curiosity: how does this work? Does the compiler duplicate the code of class A and add this additional print only in one of them and basically creates two classes, let’s say “A_with_print” and “A_without_print” and replace A<true> with “A_with_print” and A<false> with “A_without_print” when I instantiate an object of class A?

Comment: Yes it will basicly dupe the code. As a template parameter you can pass ints, or even types too. When the compiler sees template<bool b>A() it will remember it exsists. Later when you call A<true>(); It will compie __A__true when it sees A<false> it compiles __A__false. if we had an int not a bool it generates a new function for each new int we passed (it wont generate the same twice) see more at: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/